# Error when building the MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error in select query line. Here it is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING

And the code:

```php
<?php
    include('dbconnection.php');

    $sql = "select * from 'user' where id ='.$_REQUEST['id'].' "; 
    $result = mysql_query( $sql);

    if(!$result )
    {
         die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: The `echo` line - what's going on there? You can't echo and assign at the same time. You have a SQL injection vuln waiting to happen on this line too.

Comment: I just saw whether that line is working . Its printing the line with echo thats all. The error is there still after removing echo and exit.!

Comment: Do you have a table named "user" and column "id" in lowercase? What's error with the updated SQL queries now?

Comment: Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1..
This is the error i get again .!!

Comment: Change the apostrophes around `user` to be backticks. Apostrophes are for strings, not database entity names.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $sql="select * from `user` where id ='".$_REQUEST['id']."' ";
```

This will solves your problem But look [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to limit your SQL-injection vulnerability.

Comment: You've replicated the SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''. i get this error after correcting as yu said.

Comment: paste the full error so i  can check it..

Comment: @halfer thanks for mentioning it

Comment: You're welcome. However, copying and pasting part of someone else's answer is not really within the spirit of the thing here. Use your own words? `:-/`

Comment: Would you like a moderator report for plagiarism?

Comment: ok man i change my wording so kindly patience.

Answer (score 0):

Replace query:

```
$sql="select * from 'user' where id ='.$_REQUEST['id'].' ";
```

with:

```
$sql="select * from `user` where id =".$_REQUEST['id']."";
```

Comment: You've replicated the SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @halfer At this time his problem is syntax error and SQL injection is something else.

Comment: @Iffi is right, but it's worth mentioning in the answer that even though the code resolves the syntax error it's vulnerable to injections.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$id  = (int) $_REQUEST['id']; // interger value
$sql = "select * from `user` where id = '$id' ";
```